# java.lang.ClassCastException:com.eltoh.date.onboarding.screens.FavouriteListFragment cannot cast to com.eltoh.date.onboarding.screens.ChatListFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, classcastexception, android-viewpager2

I tried to execute a method in a specific fragment from the ViewPager2 fragment of that fragment.
It works fine on startup, but when moving between other fragments in ViewPager and back again for that specific fragment, this error appears and the class cast exception is thrown. If anyone can help solve this error, Thank you...

ViewPager adapter

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(list: ArrayList<Fragment>, fm: FragmentManager, lifeCycle: Lifecycle):
    FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifeCycle) {
    private val fragmentList = list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }
}
```

The required method in ChatListFragment

```
fun clearAdapter() {
        chatListAdapter.clearList()
        chatListAdapter.getSelectedItem().clear()
        chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Fragments list in ViewPager

```
val fragmentList by lazy { arrayListOf(
            GroupListFragment(),
            ChatListFragment(),
            FavouriteListFragment(),
            StatusListFragment(),
            CallsListFragment()
        ) }
```

Method calling in a ViewPager fragment, and here is the error that appears after moving between different fragments in ViewPager.

```
val fm: FragmentManager = childFragmentManager
                val fragM: ChatListFragment = fm.findFragmentById(ChatListFragment().id) as ChatListFragment
                fragM.clearAdapter()
```

....................

Answer (score 0):

`val fragM: ChatListFragment = fm.findFragmentById(ChatListFragment().id) as ChatListFragment`

What you can do before typecasting is first to make sure the class is of type ChatListFragment using

```
if(fm.findFragmentById(ChatListFragment().id) is ChatListFragment){
    // Todo
}
```

Comment: This can be done in many other ways, and can be done using try{ } & catch{ }.
I want a way to make the current fragment id always equals to ChatListFragment().

Comment: Update your question!